# Avoid deadlock using Popen without using sleep (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, deadlock

I have a problem with deadlock using this Python script that parses the output produced
piping two programs and stores the result in a directory x.

```
import subprocess as sp
from time import sleep

p1 = sp.Popen(['executable_1'], stdout=sp.PIPE , stderr = sp.STDOUT)
p2 = sp.Popen(['executable_2'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout = sp.PIPE)

x = my_parser(p2.stdout)
```

However if I change the script using `p2 = sp.Popen(executable_2, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout = sp.PIPE, preexec_fn = time.sleep(0.1))` everything seems to be working fine.

The solution though doesn't seem very clean to me. I understand that waiting for a bit of time I give the possibility to p1 to flush its output to stdout, (although if I manually try `p1.stdout.flush()` I sometimes get IOError as well).

I can't use communicate() because the output of p2 is quite large and I want to process the data while `executable_2` is still in execution.

How can I prevent the deadlock in this case without using sleep()?

Comment: This makes no sense. You are executing a sleep at the moment you call popen and pass None to preexec_fn. If you wanted it to sleep after the fork, wouldn't you want to pass a partial or lambda that sleeps? What you are doing is effectively calling a sleep before your popen runs.

Comment: You are right jdi. Actually after a long painful debugging I discovered that it was caused by a bug that only appears in ipython with QT4Agg backend when printing a large output (which was done by myparser which during the development printed the ouput of the command.) See here where I reported the bug: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3884 )